# Get form values in json format on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am trying to get form values in json format on button click the code is..

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var form = $("#user_info");
    var data =form.serialize();
    console.log(data)
```

but i am getting values like

```
userfnmae=xyz&userlname=xyz&useremail=a@b.com&useremail= xyz&usercity=zzz&userlocation=abc&userproduct=xyz&usercomment=xyz
```

but i want data in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this coding ...

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var result= {};
     $("#user_info").serializeArray().map(function(item) {
        if ( result[item.name] ) {
            if ( typeof(result[item.name]) === "string" ) {
                result[item.name] = [config[item.name]];
            }
            result[item.name].push(item.value);
        } else {
            result[item.name] = item.value;
        }
    });
 console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> Use [`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/#serializeArray) => *Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values*

Try this:

```js
$('#g').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('#user_info').serializeArray();
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='user_info'>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="a" value="1" id="a">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="b" value="2" id="b">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" id="c">
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea name="d" rows="8" cols="40">4</textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="e">
      <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="f" value="8" id="f">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g">
  </div>
</form>
```